# Avoid to popback to specific fragment with Navigation Architecture Component

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation

I have two navigation flow with Navigation Architecture Component :

```
A > B > C
```

And

```
A > X > C
```

In the first flow, `popBackStack()` works as expected.
But I want a different behavior in the second flow. I dont want to popback to **Fragment X** but directly to **Fragment A**.

Because **Fragment C** is accessible by several ways, I can't use a fixed `destinationId` in `popBackStack(destinationId,inclusive)`.

Any solution ? May be navigation direction config ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this action for x to c.

```
<fragment
android:id="@+id/x"
...
>
 <action
            android:id="@+id/action_X_to_C"
            app:destination="@id/C"
            app:popUpTo="@id/A" >
        </action>
</fragment>
```

In fragmentX

```
findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_x_to_C)
```